# Is an HTTP request considered idempotent if changes a record's last modified time?

Tags: http

Suppose that I have a table called `persons` and that a request to change any information about a person also updates that record's `last_modified` column. Would such a request still be considered idempotent? What I'm trying to find out is if auxiliary fields can be exempted from the criteria of idempotence.

Comment: That depends: if the request is made again and nothing changes this time, would the modification date actually be updated?

Comment: Why would you update the last modified time if nothing else was modified? Seems a little redundant/ incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If any information is changed on the database after a request (a POST request obviously, you would not alter a person record on a GET request) then it's **not indempotent**. By definition. Unless you only store stats (like logs).

Here it's not the `last_modified` column which is important, it's the ***change*** any information about a person.

A GET request is indempotent, you can take any uri and put it in an `<IMG>` in a web page, browsers will load it without asking, it must not alter anything in the database, or in the session (like destroying a session is not indempotent). An indempotent request can be prefetched, can run in any prioity (no need to care about the order of several indempotent queries,none of them can impact the other), etc.